# azure portal login authentication

Tags: azure, portal

Every time I login to the Azure portal, it always calls my phone to verify, I have to answer the phone, and punch in #. How do I get rid of this annoying process?

Answer (score 1):

Disable multi-factor authentication (MFA), see here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-manage-settings/ and here: https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/using-azure-multi-factor-authentication-with-azure-active-directory-and-sharepoint-2013/.

Comment: You can install the Microsoft Authenticator app to at least avoid the phone call. You still need to approve the request, tho. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/end-user/microsoft-authenticator-app-how-to

Answer (score 0):

Somehow either you or anyone else managing your subscription have enabled Multi Factor Authentication. You need to disable that for your user.

You or your subscription administrator must have done this for you: [Use mobile phone as your contact method with Azure Multi-Factor Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-first-time-mobile-phone/)